# How to use HttpClient to get non-primitive types in MVC 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc

I have the following WebAPI client code in an MVC 6 project:

```
public async Task<Blog> GetData()
{
    Blog result = null;

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:55792/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        // New code:
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/values/1");
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            result = await response.Content.???;
            return result;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

I can't use it, as the DNX core does not support WebAPI.Client NuGet package (which contains `ReadAsync<MyClass>()`)  so I have to use System.Net.Http.

It has only 3 reading functions:

1. `ReadAsByteArrayAsync`
2. `ReadAsStreamAsync`
3. `ReadAsStringAsync`

None of them can read an arbitrary typed object.

What should I use now?

Comment: What data type you get from WebAPI? JSON? XML? Other?
Why not just to read result as string and then parse it to appropriate object manually?

Comment: The data is JSON. I intend to get the data according to `ReadAsync<MyClass>()`, so I don't have to parse the string _manually_.

Comment: Easy enough, NewtonSoft is a popular library: `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(resultAsString);`

Comment: Thanks, it is DNX-compatible. If you change it to an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can deserialize the JSON, Newtonsoft is one popular library:

```
...
string payload = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(payload);
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Not tested code, but completed code here with [download](http://dotnetawesome.com/webapi/Part2-How-to-retrieve-data-from-the-database-in-the-aspnet-web-API-using-HttpClient) option

```
           public ActionResult Part2()
            {
                List<Employee> list = new List<Employee>();
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                var result = client.GetAsync("http://localhost:1963/api/Example").Result;
                if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    list = result.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<Employee>>().Result;
                }
                return View(list);
            }
```